# Django ORM create troubles

Tags: django, django-orm

Im trying to save an object, but I cant do it with this query.

```
sm = SobreMi.objects.create(usuario__usuario_id=40)
```

My models:

```
class Usuarios(models.Model):
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    foto = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()

class UsuarioEvento(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuarios)
    evento = models.ForeignKey(Eventos)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.usuario.nombres

class SobreMi(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(UsuarioEvento)
    categorias = models.ManyToManyField(EventoCategoria)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
usuario = Usuarios.objects.get(id=40)
sm = SobreMi.objects.create(usuario=usuario)
```

But this is also possible:

```
sm = SobreMi.objects.create(usuario_id=40)
```